How to use legacy plugins in lib mode in vite
I have a component library that needs to be compatible with lower-version browsers.
Vite does not automatically read my browserslistrc configuration. So I used the legacy plugin.
But it reports an error "@vitejs/plugin-legacy does not support library mode."
If I want to package a component library and must use lib mode. How should I do it?
export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    outDir: 'dist',
    cssTarget: 'chrome61',
    lib: {
      entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.ts'),
      name: 'treeview',
      fileName: 'index',
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      external: ['react', 'react-dom'],
      output: {
        globals: {
          react: 'react',
          'react-dom': 'react-dom',
        },
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    libcss(),
    react(),
    legacy({
      targets: ['since 2020'],
    }),
    typescript({
      target: 'es5',
      rootDir: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/'),
      declaration: true,
      declarationDir: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/types'),
      exclude: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/**'),
      allowSyntheticDefaultImports: true,
    }),
  ],
})

Or is there a way I can use the babel config directly?

I'm currently investigating this myself and have no secure answer. But check this issue out which contain some examples of babel configurations that are claimed to work. https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/1639
